# Android Native SIP Client Configuration

Tags: android, sip

Is it possible to configure Android native SIP client from your own android application (username,password and server IP) ??. I want to create android application when user installs it, the application automatically import SIP account from my server and configure (username,password and server IP) in Android native SIP client..
I have created my own SIP client using SIP Demo tutorial but it has poor voice quality and many other problems..So now i want to use Android native SIP client

Comment: hey @Zain can you solve your problem? I need some help with the offical sipdemo. I've never registered to my sip server. I alywas getting failed error. Can you help me? please write me : mehmetakifalp@gmail.com

Comment: @mehmetakifalp post new question on SO with error code and problem.

Answer (score 2):

Android provides an API that supports the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP). This lets you add SIP-based internet telephony features to your applications. Android includes a full SIP protocol stack and integrated call management services that let applications easily set up outgoing and incoming voice calls, without having to manage sessions, transport-level communication, or audio record or playback directly

visit this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Comment: Thanks but question is that can we control android native sip client through this API..for example configuring sip user name ,password and sip server IP through my own android application..Read my question completely

Comment: Yes, android has a core such as example pjsua

Comment: pjsua(pjsip) - Open Source SIP Stack, library for building SIP-application